# Oracle Single value Field Data type

Tags: database, oracle, performance

I have table with `Status` column in which values like **CheckOut**, **Stayover** etc may be stored. Now for creating its data type, I may use `varchar` column to store these values as it is but my concern is over performance as well as values comparison in application where we may have to use `trim` function for removing space around values.

Should I store it in number 1, 2 , 3 ..  or in char as 'S', 'C' etc and then compare these in application?

Let me know what data type would be better to store it: `Number` vs `Char`

For example, is that affect performance if we want it as:

```
field='S'
or
field=1
```

Comment: How many records you will retrieve at once and check/compare their status ? 1 thousand, 100 thousands, 1 million, 100 millions ?

Comment: not sure, may be more than this

Comment: My advice would be a short varchar2 column, storing a fixed-length alpha code, with another two-column table to relate the codes to a descriptive name. Give some real thought to the codes to come up with a standard that meets current needs but also allows for future additions without painting yourself into a corner.  This really isn't specific to any database product.  It is fundamental data design.

Comment: I understand that you mean to use like field='S'. Can you tell the advantage over using this one of the two above.

Comment: How about running some comparative tests and see the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The NUMBER datatype in Oracle is stored as a BCD (Binary Coded
>   Decimal) which is, in effect, a string type. So comparison of a number
>   and a varchar/char is essentially the same. The only difference is
>   that character data types go through the NLS layer, so that takes a
>   teensy bit longer, but I've found the difference to be negligible.

So I recommend **Use numbers whenever possible** as operation of integer data is faster than character data.

[Detail discussion here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2048810500346778955)

Comment: You should read all of that AskTom thread you link to.  It doesn't support your assertion at all.  "in general, compare a str to a str and it is as fast as comparing a number to a number "

Answer (score 2):

For those interested in some metrics, here are a series of SQL statements to test a query on a one character column (VARCHAR2(1)) and a 1 digit column (NUMBER(1)).

Test setup - create a 100,000,000 row table with a character status column and a numeric status column. Run a simple query to count the rows using a character status filter and compare its timing with running a similar query using the numeric status.

**Executive summary - the difference is hardly noticeable.**

```
SQL> create table some_100_rows
  2  as
  3  select rownum as rnum
  4  from dual
  5  connect by level <= 100;

Table created.

SQL> create table some_1000000_rows
  2  as
  3  select ROWNUM as id
  4       , cast(case when mod(rownum, 2) = 0 then 'S' else 'C' end as varchar2(1)) as varchar_status
  5       , cast(case when mod(rownum, 2) = 0 then 1 else 2 end as number(1)) as num_status
  6    from dual
  7   connect by level <= 1000000
  8   ;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.46
```

(I'm keeping the data and distribution simple so the character search and number search were doing the same thing and the difference in timing should be due to datatypes alone.)

```
SQL>  create table test_varchar_vs_number -- a table of 100,000,000 rows
  2   as
  3   select t1.*
  4   from some_1000000_rows t1
  5        cross join
  6        some_100_rows t2
  7  ;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:37.96

SQL> select count(*)
  2    from test_varchar_vs_number
  3  ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
 100000000

Elapsed: 00:00:10.54
```

Note that just to count the table only takes around 10 seconds.

Here's what the contents look like:

```
SQL>  select *
  2   from test_varchar_vs_number
  3   where rownum < 11;

        ID VARCHAR_STATUS NUM_STATUS
---------- -------------- ----------
         1              C          2
         2              S          1
         3              C          2
         4              S          1
         5              C          2
         6              S          1
         7              C          2
         8              S          1
         9              C          2
        10              S          1

10 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
```

Run a select to count the number of rows with an "S" in the VARCHAR_STATUS column. Repeat a few times to get a stable metric.

```
SQL> select count(*)
  2    from test_varchar_vs_number
  3   where varchar_status = 'S'
  4   ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  50000000

**Elapsed: 00:00:11.82**

SQL> select count(*)
  2    from test_varchar_vs_number
  3   where varchar_status = 'S'
  4   ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  50000000

**Elapsed: 00:00:11.05**

SQL> select count(*)
  2    from test_varchar_vs_number
  3   where varchar_status = 'S'
  4   ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  50000000

**Elapsed: 00:00:11.37**
```

So just over 11 seconds to count 50,000,000 "S" rows.

Now try the same thing with rows with a 1 in the NUMBER_STATUS column:

```
SQL> select count(*)
  2    from test_varchar_vs_number
  3   where num_status = 1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  50000000

**Elapsed: 00:00:11.04**

SQL> select count(*)
  2    from test_varchar_vs_number
  3   where num_status = 1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  50000000

**Elapsed: 00:00:10.79**

SQL> select count(*)
  2    from test_varchar_vs_number
  3   where num_status = 1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  50000000

**Elapsed: 00:00:10.59**
```

So, the difference is negligible. (Min chacter search time: 11.05s vs Min number search time 10.59s.)

EDIT:
For those interested in the low level details, here are the stats from a 10046 trace put through tkprof. This is a separate run from above so don't expect the times to exactly match. (Keep in mind that the total times are for all 3 of the runs of the query.)

```
select count(*)
  from test_varchar_vs_number
 where num_status = 1

call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        3      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      3      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        6     11.85      34.30     621984     622005          0           3
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total       12     11.85      34.30     621984     622005          0           3

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 110  
Number of plan statistics captured: 3

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
         1          1          1  SORT AGGREGATE (cr=207335 pr=207328 pw=0 time=11434679 us)
  50000000   50000000   50000000   TABLE ACCESS FULL TEST_VARCHAR_VS_NUMBER (cr=207335 pr=207328 pw=0 time=10113986 us cost=56992 size=150000000 card=50000000)


Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  SQL*Net message to client                       6        0.00          0.00
  reliable message                                1        0.00          0.00
  enq: KO - fast object checkpoint                1        0.13          0.13
  direct path read                             4835        0.29         22.04
  SQL*Net message from client                     6        0.01          0.04
********************************************************************************


select count(*)
  from test_varchar_vs_number
 where varchar_status = 'S'

call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        3      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      3      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        6     11.20      33.43     621984     622005          0           3
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total       12     11.20      33.43     621984     622005          0           3

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 110  
Number of plan statistics captured: 3

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
         1          1          1  SORT AGGREGATE (cr=207335 pr=207328 pw=0 time=11146155 us)
  50000000   50000000   50000000   TABLE ACCESS FULL TEST_VARCHAR_VS_NUMBER (cr=207335 pr=207328 pw=0 time=9700296 us cost=56940 size=100000000 card=50000000)


Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  SQL*Net message to client                       6        0.00          0.00
  reliable message                                1        0.00          0.00
  enq: KO - fast object checkpoint                1        0.21          0.21
  direct path read                             4873        0.25         22.12
  SQL*Net message from client                     6        0.03          0.05
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks, Its a proof of my answer

Comment: Wall-clock timings are notoriously meaningless. Without indexes the execution path is always a full table scan; the WHERE clause filtering is a negligible part of the total elapsed time.  Sorry to be so down, when you've put so much effort into it.

Comment: @APC There are no indexes; the SQL above is all there is. I did actually do a run with bitmap indexes and the timings went down to about 0.01 seconds for both number and character searches.I will include the execution plans and the TKPROF info (including wait events) for completeness.

Comment: @APC Sorry, I think I misread your comment. Yes, definitely full table scans but over that many rows I think it shows that it doesn't matter which datatype is chosen; it's not going to be your biggest concern in a case like this.